# Disabling chrome data saver while debugging

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, android-datasaver, chrome-datasaver

I'm trying to inspect a website on chrome for Android with chrome dev tools on my pc.

First of all, i check data saver is disabled for chrome on Android and it is

[image: Screenshot]

Then, i connect my phone with my pc, run chrome dev tools and i get the warning

> Considering disabling Chrome Data Saver while debugging.

Why do I get this message if data saver on chrome for Android is disabled?

The problem is that debugging is impossible, because I get a blank screen

[image: Screenshot debugger]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think it is still an open issue. Ref - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455981

Comment: I am seeing this as well. The real kicker for me though is that Chrome was still using the cached and compressed stylesheet, even though I loaded the new stylesheet in another tab. Usually that replaces the cached version, but not on Chrome for Android, apparently. To download the new stylesheet I had to clear Chrome's cache.

Answer (score 0):

does this mean that they will just remove the alert and still keep people using the Chrome Data Saver functionality while debugging?

> [Devtools] Moved chrome data saver warning to console Removes the
>   infobar for "Please consider disabling chrome data saver" and moved it
>   into the console instead through the NetworkLog. We will now sniff the
>   headers looking for the chrome proxy and show the console message only
>   when we see the main resource was loaded with the proxy header
>   present. see b/63351364 for new p-link request.

source https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455981

Comment: As I understand it, the point of this change is that in older chrome versions, the banner would always show, whether data saver was enabled or not.  From whatever version of chrome this change was first included in (62?) the banner only shows if the browser being debugged loads a page that looks like it has been compressed by data saver.